# CasperJS setInterval, synchronous execution

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to simulate a mouse drift with CasperJS. To achieve that, i want to use a setInterval. The interval is defined in another file, just using require() to get it. I can execute it, but Casper doesn't wait for the interval to be finished. The interval runs about 200ms, then Casper goes on with code execution. When drift() is finished, it calls the "finished" callback.

How can i tell CasperJS to wait until finished() is executed?

```
casper.waitFor(function () {
  var result = drift({
    ...
    finished: function (x,y) {
      //casper.test.comment('up ' + x + ' ' + y);
      that.mouse.up(x, y);
    }
  }, window);

  return result;
}, function () { /** test here... **/ });

function drift (options, window) {
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter <= limit) {
      x += stepX;
      y += stepY;
      //call the way callback    
      options.way(x, y);
      counter += 1;
    } else {  
      options.finished(x, y);
      ...
      window.clearInterval(interval);
      returnVal = true;
    }
  }, 50);
  return returnVal;
}
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/schickling/Overscroll/blob/testing/test/drift.js
And here: https://github.com/schickling/Overscroll/blob/testing/test/modules/drift-move.js